# Textbook with proof that product of two Gaussian functions is also Gaussian

Tags: probability-theory

I know that the product of two Gaussian functions is also Gaussian function. This is stated in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function), but I might need to cite a classical (text)book/paper stating this result. A book containing the proof is welcome. Could you name such a book?

Comment: This is really just a simple consequence of well-kown identities concerning [powers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation).

Comment: @Rasmus: Thanks, I didn't think before asking :|. I maintain the question only because of @John's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The product of two independent normal (Gaussian) random variables is *not* normal.  That would be convenient, but it's not true.  Here are a some related theorems that are true:

- The *sum* of two independent normal random variables is normal.
- The product of two independent *log normal* random variables is log normal.
- The ratio of two independent normal random variables is Cauchy.

For more on distribution relationships, see this [chart](http://www.johndcook.com/distribution_chart.html).

If you multiply two normal PDFs you get the joint PDF of a *multivariate* normal, i.e. if f(x) is a normal PDF then g(x, y) defined by f(x)g(y) is a multivariate normal PDF, but in that case you're multiplying *densities* and not *random variables*.

**Update**: I looked back at your question and I see you said Gaussian "function," rather than "random variable", so perhaps you had in mind the PDF result I mentioned above. If so, just write down the definition of multivariate normal and there it is.

**Update 2**: Here's an explicit formula for the the product of two normal pdfs being proportional to another normal pdf: [blog post](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2012/10/29/product-of-normal-pdfs/).

Comment: Unfortunately John's blog post doesn't contain the full derivation. Would anyone like to contribute a line-by-line proof? Or cite a textbook that has one?